# Windows 10 won't let me set HDMI monitor to higher resolutions

Tags: windows, hdmi

I have a Dell Precision 5530 with an Dell external docking station. I have connected to the docking station, 4 HP e240C monitors. I connect 3 of them to the DisplayPort adapters on the docking station.

Since it only supports 3 monitors, via the docking station, I ordered and installed a StarTech UDP32HD4K external USB DisplayPort adapter to hook up a 4th monitor. It has been working since I bought it in Jan 2020. I had 4 monitors working perfectly.

2 wks ago, the 4th monitor, on the HDMI port went out. I replaced the docking station and now have HDMI output. HOWEVER, it will not let me set the resolution of the monitor on the HDMI port to anything other than 720x576, 720x480, or 640x480. The internal display adapters are:
Intel UHD Graphics 630
NVIDIA Quadro P1000
USB3.0 UHD DisplayPort Adapter (StarTech)
(Not sure which one controls the HDMI port)

On occasion, the monitor on the HDMI port would go bonkers and show a jumbled up screen. I'm at a loss here why this HDMI output has changed, I even changed out the HDMI cable.

Any ideas on what I should do here?

Comment: What revision of HDMI does the docking port support?

Comment: I have no idea how to determine that. IT was working perfectly before at 1920 x 1080

Comment: Please look up the exact model number of the docking station and add that to your question. Without knowing what specific docking station is used we can only guess.

Comment: It is a Dell WD19S. MY PC (Precision 5530) only supports HBR2 but the display resolution table says it should support 1920 x 1080    https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/dell-wd19tb-dock/wd19_tb_userguide/display-resolution-table?guid=guid-5558fc88-5c31-4e2c-90be-42359855a1ae